# Corona App in Angular - Dynamic Word/Table Wrap as per Table values - Unable to generate withinin A4

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

[image][image: Example Display]I am developing a inspection sheet for Health inspector to inspect the House with people who have corona symptoms, So based on the area we have a measuring Frequency,

Say If i have a area of 100 people where there is already someone affected by corona then my measuring Frequency is 100% then, there will be 100 boxes generated, 1 for each person,then Health Inspector can put a tick against the name if they have any symptoms. Everything is perfect and I am able to generate 100 boxes but only horizontally, because of which I am not able to printout in A4,

I am looking for soultion to wrap the table at the end of A4 and get it below in the same page until it ends. Kindly suggest please. What should I do it wrap the content at the end of A4 sheet and go down.

The below HTML I have tried few but unable to succeed.

```
**
    <table *ngFor="let col of item.headers2">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>{{ col }}</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr *ngFor="let subItem of item.subdata; let j = index">
        <td>{{subItem[col]}}</td>
      </tr>

    </table>**
```

Json data looks like,

```
[![{

"headers": \[sno,name,1,2,3,4,.........,150\],


"subItem": \[

{Sno:1, name: xxx},
{Sno:2, name:yyy},
{Sno:3, name:aaa}
\]
}][1]][1]
```

Updated code.

Comment: Maybe a css grid is a better solution?

Comment: Sure, Let me check sir.

Comment: @MikeOne No a Grid is also not giving desired output.